# ¿Cómo saber que valor se envió de un input/form AJAX?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente formulario donde se introduce un código de trabajador.

```
<form id="tck" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="ticket" maxlength="10">
 <button type="submit">ticket</button>
</form>
```

Y estos datos son enviados por medio de `AJAX`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".dismiss").click(function () {
    $(".response").fadeOut(500);
  });

  $(document).on('submit', '#tck', function () {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'employee.php',
      data: data,
      success: function (response) {
        //$(".response").html(response);
        $(".response>span.message").html(response);
        $(".response").fadeIn(200);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          $('.response').fadeOut(500);
        }, 6000);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Entonces, lo que yo necesito es saber que valor se envió en el siguiente `input` y guardarlo en una `session`.

**¿Cómo puedo saber que dato se envió en el campo `input`?**

Comment: En el archivo **`employee.php`** al que mandas la petición Ajax, puedes recuperar los valores del formulario mediante `_$POST` en este caso, porque es el método del formulario. En POST has de usar la etiqueta `name` del elemento. Una forma inteligente de hacerlo es la siguiente: **`$ticket = isset($_POST['ticket']) ? $_POST['ticket'] : '';`** Lo que se hace ahí es usar el operador ternario para evaluar si hay un dato llamado `ticket` en el POST , si lo hay se la asigna a la variable `$ticket` y si no lo hay, la variable `$ticket` se quedará en blanco o, si quieres le puedes asignar otro valor.

Comment: @A.Cedano Esto `$ticket = isset($_POST['ticket']) ? $_POST['ticket'] : ''; ` debo añadirlo en la página `employee.php`  y en la página donde está el `ajax`  no se añade nada solo vasta con imprimir `echo $ticket `

Comment: En el PHP tú pones el `echo` pero luego, en Ajax, debes presentar en algún elemento del HTML la respuesta, en caso de que no haya ningún error. Eso se haría en el `success`, por ejemplo: Pones en el HTML un `<div id='text-response'></div>` que será el contenedor de la respuesta venida del servidor y en el `success` de Ajax: `$("#text-response").html(response);`. De ese modo, la respuesta del servidor se verá en ese div. Nótese que en jQuery, para alcanzar los elementos por su id se usará `#`.

Comment: @A.Cedano No entiendo aún, yo os tengo la respuesta de `AJAX` mediante el siguiente `div` - > `<div class="response"></div>`

Comment: @A.Cedano Os edite la pregunta, es así como os dices que realice el procedimiento?

Comment: No sabía que tenías un div en tu HTML para mostrar la respuesta, así que he propuesto agregar uno. Eso lo puedes dejar como lo tenías, ya que es lo de menos. Lo importante es que entiendas el funcionamiento. Si decides dejarlo como lo tienes ahora, en mi respuesta cambia esto: `$('#respuesta').html(response);` por esto: `$('.response').html(response);` y listo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cuestión funciona de esta manera:

### A. Del lado del cliente: `index.php`

Tienes un formulario y código Javascript/jQuery que se encarga de enviar la petición Ajax.

Lo que hace Ajax en este caso es enviar/recibir cosas desde y hacia el servidor a través de un archivo que se ejecuta del lado del servidor. En tu ejemplo ese archivo sería `employee.php`.

Es importante que sepas que las peticiones Ajax tienen algunos métodos que sirven de ayuda para saber lo que ha ocurrido del lado del servidor. Generalmente la petición Ajax debería tener al menos un método `done` y otro método `fail`.  El método `done` haría casi lo mismo que tu actual método `success`, pero éste último es obsoleto desde jQuery 3, por lo tanto es mejor usar `done`.

Bien, entonces, dentro de `done` se manejara la posible respuesta exitosa del lado del servidor. Allí se podrá recoger lo que respondió el servidor y operar con esos datos, para mostrarlos por pantalla o para cualquier otra cosa.

Pero la petición puede fallar. En ese caso, deberás implementar un método `fail` el cual informará del fallo y de la posible causa del mismo.

#### El código del lado del cliente sería entonces este. Aquí pongo `index.php` completo.

He hecho varios cambios. Entre ellos, he puesto el action en el formulario directamente, de ese modo el código jQuery es más uniforme. **Una cosa muy importante es que para que funcione la URL del archivo `employee.php` debe ser correcta. Como la tienes ahora, debe estar en la misma carpeta donde corre `index.php`. Si no está en la misma carpeta, debes indicarlo.**

He quitado lo del `beforeSend`... no sé si sea necesario. He dejado lo del `fadeOut` que tienes y lo del setTimeOut... aunque no queda claro para que los necesitas. Lo digo para que sepas que eso no es necesario, a no ser que lo necesites para algo.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { //document.ready es obsoleto desde jQuery 3

            $('.dismiss').click(function () {
                $('.response').fadeOut(500);
            });

            $('#tck').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();     

                var data = $(this).serialize();

                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).prop("action"),
                    method: $(this).prop('method'),
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "html"
                });

                request.done(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                        $('.response').html(response);
                        $(".response").fadeIn(200);
                        window.setTimeout(function () {
                            $('.response').fadeOut(500);
                        }, 6000);

                });

                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert('Hubo un error: ' + textStatus);
                });         

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="tck" method="POST" action="employee.php">
    <input type="text" name="ticket" maxlength="10">
    <button type="submit">ticket</button>
</form>

<div class='response' id='respuesta'></div>

</body>
</html>
<?php


?>
```

---

### B. Del lado del servidor:  `employee.php`

El contenido de `employee.php` deberá manejar los datos enviados a través de `data` en la petición jQuery. En este caso se trata del contenido de un formulario serializado.

Una forma de evaluar si los elementos esperados tienen datos es usar `isset` en un operador ternario.

El PHP se vería así más o menos:

```
$ticket = isset($_POST['ticket']) ? $_POST['ticket'] : 'No había nada en ticket';
echo $ticket;
```

Si todo va bien, implementando este código, verás en el `div` con `id='respuesta'`  el contenido de la variable `$ticket`.

Desde PHP se pueden enviar otro tipo de datos, por ejemplo un objeto JSON completo... u otras cosas.

> El `echo` tiene lugar en el servidor **(B)**, y tú lo recoges en el
>   cliente **(A)**, dentro del método `done` de la petición Ajax.

Las posibilidades de Ajax son en ese sentido muy interesantes, por ejemplo obtener  información en el servidor y actualizar el contenido que se presenta en pantalla de forma dinámica, sin tener que refrescar la página...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69509/discussion-between-gph-and-a-cedano).