# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se envíe el form principal al ejecutar el form que esta dentro del form principal?

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Realmente no se si este bien añadir un `form` dentro de otro `form`

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="form" name="form" action="#">
    <div>
     <!-- Datos que se enviaran por medio del form principal -->
    </div>
    <div>
     <!-- Resultado de ajax que se enviaran por medio del form principal -->
     <form id="tck" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="ticket" maxlength="10">
       <button type="submit">ticket</button>
     </form>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Pero es necesario realizarlo de esa manera, porque es parte del diseño, al añadirlo fuera del `form` principal, el `input` de buscar el ticket quedaría fuera del diseño del `div`

Existe alguna forma de evitar que el segundo `form` ejecute ambos `form` o es posible evitar el uso del form para enviar datos por ajax, es decir en vez de tomar toda la información del `<form id="tck" method="post"></form>` tomar toda la información desde un `div` ejemplo `<div id="remplazoporelformsegundario"></div>` para así evitar que el segundo `form` ejecute ambos `form`.

**Mi código ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { //document.ready es obsoleto desde jQuery 3

        $('.dismiss').click(function () {
            $('.response').fadeOut(500);
        });

        $('#tck').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();     

            var data = $(this).serialize();

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: $(this).prop("action"),
                method: $(this).prop('method'),
                data: data,
                dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                    $('.response').html(response);
                    $(".response").fadeIn(200);
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.response').fadeOut(500);
                    }, 6000);

            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert('Hubo un error: ' + textStatus);
            });         

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Se puede sugerir ajax como solucion?

Comment: @Einer Perfecto amigo no hay problema, por eso añadi el ajax para ver qué posible solución se me pueda sugerir :)

Comment: Este HTML no es válido. En HTML no puede haber formularios dentro de formularios (puedes tener múltiples formularios en una página pero no deben anidarse, [referencia en la definición de HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element)).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Y entonces qué solución puedo obtener, no puedo mover ese `input` de ese `form` es parte del diseño en ese `div`

Comment: ¿A cuál de los `div` te refieres? ¿a `.container` o al que hay dentro? ¿por qué no se puede mover de ese `div`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Al div del segundo `form` no añadí más detalle por no hacer extenso el código pero no se puede mover de ese `div` porque es parte del diseño, al moverlo quedaría fuera de la estructura del diseño, si ese no fuera el caso no preguntaría esta pregunta.

Comment: Comprendo, pero entonces el verdadero problema es el diseño: el error ocurre porque hay un `form` dentro de otro `form` que es algo que el estándar de HTML dice que no se debe hacer. Las soluciones propuestas son buenas pero tratan los síntomas (el `form` externo se envía cuando se envía el interno) y no la causa del problema (no debería haber un `form` dentro de otro). Otros problemas pueden surgir más adelante porque la causa real sigue estando ahí.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no es posible con jQuery enviar y recibir información sin utilizar un forn?

Comment: @gPH sí, claro. Y entonces no necesitarías ese form ahí.  La implementación dependería un poco de lo que necesites, pero podrías tener un botón simple (no submit) que tome los valores de los input que te interesen dentro del div y los envíe vía AJAX. De ese modo el formulario no se enviaría y el HTML sería válido.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No, no lo necesito ahí.. Perfecto puedes decirme como hacerlo, como puedes observar solo es form simple donde se inserta un código y se verifica si existe o no ese ticket del empleado, y se obtiene respuesta si existe o no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la [documentación del estándar de HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element) se especifica que un formulario no puede contener a otro formulario (traducción mía, la parte importante es la del modelo de contenido):

> ### 4.10.3 El elemento `form`
>
> #### Categorías:
>
> Contenido de flujo.
>   Contenido palpable/evidente.
>
> #### Contextos en los que se puede usar este elemento:
>
> Donde se espere contenido de flujo.
>
> #### Modelo de contenido:
>
> Contenido de flujo, pero sin ningún elemento `form` descendiente.
>
> #### Omisión de etiquetas en texto/html:
>
> Ninguna etiqueta se puede omitir.

Las soluciones propuestas son buenas y solventarán el problema, pero tratan los síntomas (el `form` externo se envía cuando se envía el interno) y no la causa real del error (no debería haber un `form` dentro de otro). Otras incidencias podrían surgir más adelante porque la raíz del problema sigue estando ahí.

Lo ideal sería cambiar el diseño para que no haya un elemento `form` dentro de otro elemento `form`. Podrías seguir enviando el contenido del `form` interno (el que se eliminaría) usando AJAX. Por ejemplo, el código quedaría así:

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="form" name="form" action="#">
    <div>
     <!-- Datos que se enviaran por medio del form principal -->
    </div>
    <div>
     <!-- Resultado de ajax que se enviaran por medio del form principal -->
     <!-- cambia la etiqueta form por un div, o elimínala directamente -->
     <div id="tck">
       <input type="text" name="ticket" maxlength="10">
       <!-- cambia el tipo de submit a button para que no envíe el formulario -->
       <button type="submit">ticket</button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Y con JavaScript entonces harías algo así:

```
// cuando se pulse el botón dentro de #tck
$("#tck input[type=button]").on("click", function() {

  // lee el valor del input con nombre ticket ticket
  var ticket = $(this).closest("#tck").find("[name=ticket]").val();

  // envíalo via AJAX a la URL que se enviaba el formulario
  $.ajax({
    "url": "URL-A-LA-QUE-QUIERAS-ENVIAR-LOS-DATOS",
    "data": { "ticket":  ticket }
    // aquí puedes añadir done/success/error para procesar la vuelta
  })

});
```

De este modo, cuando se pulse el botón, solamente los datos de ese ticket en particular se enviarán y no todo el formulario como antes. Además, habrás solucionado el problema de tener HTML no válido, porque ya no habrá formularios anidados.

Que aplicado al código que tenías sería así:

```
// #tck ya no es un form, así que es el click del botón que desencadena los eventos
$("#tck input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
    e.preventDefault();     

    // serializas los inputs del div #tck
    var data = $("#tck :input").serialize();
    var $tck = $("#tck");

    var request = $.ajax({
        // para esto deberías añadir data-action y data-method al div #tck
        url: $tck.data("action"),
        method: $tck.data("method"),
        data: data,
        dataType: "html"
    });

    // a partir de aquí no hay cambios
    request.done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
            $('.response').html(response);
            $(".response").fadeIn(200);
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('.response').fadeOut(500);
            }, 6000);

    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert('Hubo un error: ' + textStatus);
    });         

});
```

Comment: Además, el motivo dado para mantener el error es este: *Pero es necesario realizarlo de esa manera, porque es parte del diseño, al añadirlo fuera del form principal, el input de buscar el ticket quedaría fuera del diseño del div*. Lo cual se podría resolver de múltiples maneras. Basta con replantear el diseño ligeramente.

Comment: Es claramente la respuesta a la pregunta. Y hay otro punto a considerar: como no está respetando el estándar, no hay garantías de que todos los navegadores tengan el mismo comportamiento al encontrar forms anidados.

Comment: @A.Cedano Realmente no es así amigo... Créeme que si pudiera replantear el diseño lo hubiera realizado sin problemas, por eso me atreví a preguntar si no hubiera sido ese caso no hubiera perdido el tiempo y lo hubiera realizado de la manera más fácil replantear el diseño.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Disculpa amigo pero que debo conservar en mi código ajax... Porque el mío tiene algunos parámetros en el ajax utilizando las nuevas propiedades de jQuery 3 y el Ajax aparte de eso se procede a realizar así `var request = $ajax`

Comment: @gPH al leer eso en tu pregunta entendí que por motivos de estilo que aplicas a un `div` en concreto tenías que tener un form dentro de otro form. Creo que lo único que impediría hacer las cosas correctamente es que el código fuente estuviese blindado, que no pudieras acceder a él. Si tienes acceso a modificar el código, no veo por qué tengas que ceñirte a un diseño erróneo el cual, como también se ha dicho en comentarios, podrá fallarte según el navegador, o fallar más adelante, si las nuevas versiones de los navegadores se hacen más estrictas en ese tipo de casos.

Comment: @gPH voy a editar la respuesta un poco para que se ajuste mejor al código JS que compartes. Dame un segundo.

Comment: @gPH el Ajax como lo tienes en tu pregunta está perfecto, no tienes que modificar nada ahí. Lo que Alvaro te responde en la parte de Ajax es (me parece) a modo esquemático, no que tengas que hacerlo tal y como él lo ha puesto. En las peticiones Ajax es mejor manejar el `done` y el `fail` tal y como lo tienes. Eso no es problema.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiando el button de tipo submit a un button normal:

```
 <form id="tck" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="ticket" maxlength="10">
       <input type="button" id="enviar-ticket" value="ticket" />
</form>
```

Se cambio de `button` a `input` para evitar que se haga submit al form. Luego reemplaza el evento `$('#tck').on('submit')` por `.click()`. Asignandole el evento al `button`:

```
 $('#enviar-ticket').click(function(e) {
       var data = $(this).serialize();
       ///...
```

Y ya lo demas quedaria igual. Asi se envia la información del formulario sin que se haga submit.

Código completo:

```
$(function() { //document.ready es obsoleto desde jQuery 3

    $('.dismiss').click(function () {
        $('.response').fadeOut(500);
    });

    // le asigamos el evento click al button
     $('#enviar-ticket').click(function(e) {

     // obtenemos la informacion del formulario
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: $(this).prop("action"),
            method: $(this).prop('method'),
            data: data,
            dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
                $('.response').html(response);
                $(".response").fadeIn(200);
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.response').fadeOut(500);
                }, 6000);

        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('Hubo un error: ' + textStatus);
        });         
    });
});
```

Comment: Disculpa y esto se conserva `e.preventDefault();` o no? o se elimina y se usa `var data = $(this).serialize();`

Comment: Esa parte del codigo se eliminaria. Ahora publico el codigo completo para que tengas una idea.

Comment: @gPH acabo de actualizar el codigo, dale una mirada.

Comment: Gracias ahorita mismo lo pruebo :)

Comment: no funciona, ahora al enviar no me trae ninguna respuesta

Comment: Tienes que investigar la causa. Intenta mirando la consola para verificar que no sea un error del servidor o si se te escapa un parámetro.

Comment: En la consola al dar clic me muestra toda la plantilla html desde principio a fin

Comment: Ahora que dices eso. Tienes que asignarle la url al ajax manualmente

Comment: y el siguiente mensaje `[Deprecation] synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to jQuery.min.js:4 the end user's experience. For more herl, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/`

Comment: y como lo hago porque este código es muy distinto a los que realmente se usarlos, este código ajax es de la siguiente respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121052/cómo-saber-que-valor-se-envió-de-un-input-form-ajax

Comment: que no más debo quitarle a este nuevo método de hacer peticion ajax

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71583/discussion-between-einer-and-gph).

Answer (score 0):

Al segundo forma en lugar de un button type submit, hazlo button type button.

Después a ese botón hazle un evento click y al ser clicado solo haga submit al form que quieres. Deberías agregarle un identificador al botón.

Ejemplo:

```
$("button#ticket").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("form#tck").submit();
});
```